# Write json file from Excel in IONIC Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I pass Excel file to json and I need to put the information from the object in one json file placed in assets folder.
I try using FILE component but I can not find the solution any Help please.
The ExcelData need to write to files
"""

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ExcelPage implements OnInit {

 ExcelData: any;
files= this.httpClient.get('../../assets/json/data.json')


  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ReadExcel(event:any){
    let file= event.target.files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    fileReader.onload =(e)=>{
      var wb = XLSX.read(fileReader.result,{type:'binary'});
      var sheetNames = wb.SheetNames;
      this.ExcelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheetNames[0]])
     // console.log(this.ExcelData)
      JSON.stringify(this.ExcelData)

  XLSX.writeFile(this.ExcelData, "../../assets/json/data.json")
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder is read only at run time.

You can only store files in it during development time.